# Changing the camera movement in unity

Tags: unity

I have a code that allows me to move the camera on the x-axis. I need it to move on the y-axis as well as the x.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class orbit : MonoBehaviour {


    public float turnSpeed = 4.0f;
    public Transform player;

    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start () {
        offset = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y + 8.0f, player.position.z + 7.0f);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
        transform.position = player.position + offset; 
        transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding  offset = offset + Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, transform.right) * offset; after offset=Quaternion....

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the same thing on the Y axes, like so:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
    offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, Vector3.left) * offset;
    transform.position = player.position + offset; 
    transform.LookAt(player.position);
}
```

Or perhaps even simpler like so:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    player.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, 0);
}
```

However, those two ways 'rotate based on the current orientation/rotation' of the player.

This next one will rotate the same way, no matter how the player is orientated:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Input.GetAxis( "Mouse X" ), Space.World);
    player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, Input.GetAxis( "Mouse Y" ), Space.World);
}
```

Hope that helps!